Proper Way To Drain Celery Tasks From Worker
I have a Celery worker instance that processes tasks.
When deploying an update I want to let it complete the tasks it's already working on before shutting it down. So first I want to stop it from consuming tasks...
celery -A tasks.celery control cancel_consumer celery
Then I can loop 'til I'm sure the worker has finished with any tasks that might have been started before we stopped it from consuming.
Question
How do I ensure that this worker has zero tasks in-process, in all processes (I'm using autoscale)
I know I can: celery -A tasks.celery inspect active and get:
->  celery@44a938b4d21f: OK
    - empty -

But when there are multiple processes going, will this be the response? Will there be a response for each process?? Is it really as simple as just checking that response for - empty - in line 2 of the output??
If possible, I don't want to delete the tasks, even if they would get put back into the queue and picked up later.
